# Google Sheets Data Validation Dropdown error: valid data is rejected as invalid

Tags: google-sheets, data-validation, google-sheets-data-validation

I'm trying to create a drop down list... something i've never had an issue with until GSheets modified the route in which they handle dropdown lists. Now I cannot seem to get them to work. Have tried following tutorials to see if I've missed a change and still encounter the error.

To create the below error: I select the dropdown from the cell with the list and select one of the two options I've created from the data validation inset menu. Both of the options return a rejection response.

Here is an image providing insight into my frustration:
[image]

Comment: In my case, the image doesn't help (maybe because my screen resolution  and size). Please Only use images when it's not possible or practical to explain something using text. In this case,  add the error message and the data validation settings as text. If you like you could keep the image. Personally I prefer images that doesn't take so much space... I think that you can easily reproduce the problem is a new spreadsheet using A1 an put the dialog in such way that the image takes the minimal space.

Comment: I viewed this same page on my phone. No issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cells are most likely formatted as **Format > Number > Currency** or some such number format that throws a spanner in the works. Format the cells as **Format > Number > Automatic**.

Comment: Automatic solved this.

Yes I was trying to add a custom unit suffix. I switched back to number and the issue persisted. I did modify the validation to include the suffix, but it was not a fan of that either. I can do without the specificity for now.